# Boolean algebra of the lattice of subspaces of a vector space?

Tags: lattice-theory, boolean-algebras, vector-spaces

Recall that a Boolean algebra is a complemented distributive lattice. The set of subspaces of a vector space comes very close to being a boolean algebra. It satisfies all the required properties, except being distributive. Even then it is a [modular lattice](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modular+lattice), which is almost the distributivity property. This raises the question of constructing a Boolean algebra from this complemented modular lattice. So,

- Does there exist a left (or right) adjoint to the forgetful functor $F$ from the category of Boolean algebras (and bounded-lattice homomorphisms) to that of complemented modular lattices?
- If so, what does it look like?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: the only finite Boolean lattices are the lattices of subsets of a finite set.

Comment: The lattice of subspaces of a *finite-dimensional* vector space is modular. This is not true for general vector spaces. Rather, the infinite-dimensional analogue is that the lattice of closed subspaces of a Hilbert space is what we call an *orthomodular lattice*. (As a more subjective matter, I don't know how many people would think of subspace lattices as being "very close" to being distributive. I certainly wouldn't.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming "bounded-lattice homomorphism" means what I would call "0,1-homomorphism", i.e., it takes top to top and bottom to bottom? Then there is no adjoint, left or right.

Let $L$ be the lattice of subspaces of a two-dimensional vector space $V$ (over any field). I claim that there is no 0,1-homomorphism from $L$ into any Boolean algebra. This is because we can find three one-dimensional subspaces of $V$ any two of which are complements in $L$. But then the same is true of their images under any 0,1-homomorphism, and you cannot find three elements of any Boolean algebra with this property.

So, no left adjoint to the forgetful functor because every Boolean algebra has at least one 0,1-homomorphism into the two-element Boolean algebra $\{0,1\}$ and thus there is no Boolean algebra $B$ with the property that ${\rm Hom}(B, \{0,1\}) \cong {\rm Hom}(L, \{0,1\})$.

Now let $M$ be the lattice of subspaces of the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^3$, the three-dimensional vector space over the two-element field. Letting $B_4$ be the four-element Boolean algebra, if I have calculated correctly* there are exactly fifty-eight 0,1-homomorphisms from $B_4$ into $M$. But the number of 0,1-homomorphisms from $B_4$ into any Boolean algebra is either a power of two or infinite. So there is no Boolean algebra $B$ with ${\rm Hom}(B_4, B) \cong {\rm Hom}(B_4, M)$ and thus no right adjoint.

---

${}^*$Because $M$ has sixteen elements, two of which (top and bottom) have exactly one complement, and fourteen of which have exactly four complements. So there are $2 + 14\cdot 4 = 58$ 0,1-homomorphisms from $B_4$ into $M$.

Comment: There is a trivial Boolean algebra with just one element (in which $0=1$), and it has no homomorphisms to $\{0,1\}$.  Indeed, the left adjoint exists by general nonsense--just formally adjoin a complement operation and then mod out the equivalence relation given by all the Boolean algebra axioms.  (This equivalence relation may end up making all the elements equal, so you get the trivial Boolean algebra.)

Comment: Oh, I was raised to think that 0 and 1 have to be distinct, but I now see that that dates me --- according to Wikipedia this convention is seen in "older works".

Comment: If we follow your convention, which I accept is the way things are done now, then any left adjoint would have to take every vector space of dimension at least two to the one-element Boolean algebra. (I could have said "dimension at least two" in the second paragraph.) So I suppose it's not what the OP was hoping for ...

Comment: @NikWeaver: Thank you for your nice answer. I was hoping that the left adjoint exists and be something like the Boolean subalgebra generated by all the subspaces in $2^V.$ This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Strictly speaking, I think Eric's answer is correct. Glad I could help, though!